# Can i make a project in VS2013 that targets both Windows 10 Mobile and Windows Phone 8.1, and does Windows 10 Mobile find Windows 8.1 Apps in store?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, publishing, universal, windows-10-mobile

I have made an app that targets Windows 8.1, and on my phone i am running Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview. Now while debugging with the emulator and the device i had no problems with the app, but i believe since the app is not showing up on Windows Store (App is in the store, published earlier today) while browsing with my phone it could have something to do with my version of Windows on the phone.

As the title says, can i make a project in VS2013 that targets both Windows 10 Mobile and Windows Phone 8.1 (or even 8?), and does Windows 10 Mobile find Windows 8.1 Apps in store?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if anyone who downvotes the question could justify that in the comments so I can make my questions better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. An app targeting 8.1 would show up in the new store, and anyone would be able to download it.

It's possible that your app just hasn't been published yet. The publishing process takes quite a while, from hours to a day or two. Check out your store dashboard to verify your app's progress.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked the dashboard and the app is indeed published, but did not show up in the store. But now it does, and there are a new issue, when i search the app and click on it i get an error (translated from norwegian) : **server stumbled. The page can not be loaded. Try again later.** Guess i have to take this one with MS.

Comment: Yeah, they're usually responsive when it comes to uploading new apps. Good luck.

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile can even run apps that target WP7

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 Apps will show up in the Windows 10 Store automatically.

It takes 1-2 day to be searchable on store. If it doesn't, contact Windows Store support, through dev portal, and report the issue. https://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/windows-app-support

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of the Universal Windows Platform which is new to Windows 10 (including Mobile), then that particular app wouldn't run on Windows Phone 8.1. If you're not dependent on Windows 10 specific APIs or functionalities, then you could consider targeting Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal App.

You can also create a solution with a shared project in Visual Studio 2015 (free in the community edition, in case you're up for switching over) - in that case you can have a Windows 10 (Mobile) specific binary as well as a Windows Phone 8.1 version that share some code - this would be the best of both worlds in term of target system optimisation, maintainability and avoiding code duplication.

There is a nice step-by-step guide: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/